# Who is actually receiving the loan?

Tags: loans, guarantor

Before signing for a guarantor loan for the first time, in reading the contract I'm confused by this wording

> Your payment schedule will be:
>
> - Number of Payments; 24
> - Amount of Payments; $ 177.13
> - When Payments are Due; Monthly, starting 30 days
>   after the loan is disbursed to your guarantor.

I understand the terms of repayment. I'm not clear on that last sentence. Does that mean the loan goes to the guarantor first?
And if so, what's the guarantee that guarantor will forward me the loan, that I will be responsible to pay back?

Comment: If you don't trust your guarantor, find someone else to take that role. See also answers about cosigned loans, since I think that's what this amounts to.

Comment: This is not something we can answer. Where are you? What country's laws apply? Who is the lender? Who's the guarantor? What's the situation? It could be a perfectly valid scenario, or could be a complete scam, there's no way for us to know.

Comment: Although it's not something we can answer as it stands, per @littleadv's comment, I wanted to commend you for reading and seeking to understand the small print. Too many people would not bother with that.

Comment: @starlene These are absolutely valid questions, but consider the reverse of the situation - what guarantee does the guarantor have, that you will pay back the loan? After all, if you fail to pay it back, the guarantor will be equally responsible to pay it back.

Comment: What is the loan for? (house, car, etc.)